# Must have contents/conventions for "Selenium Automation" project?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am involved in multiple projects in my company for manual testing. When we have so many test cases in the project we have to automate regression suite for those. Now problem is I have to have a portable framework that work for any project I move to. I simply import my java project(as existing maven project) and start executing selenium test cases after writing them. As of now, this is how I am doing but I don't know if this the optimum way or not.

1. I create a maven project, which gives, few `source folders` ready to use.`/myproject/src/main/java` and `/myproject/src/test/java`.
2. In `/myproject/src/test/java` folder I create a class which has `setup()` and `teardown()` methods.
3. I create another class by the name "Define" where I define variables/string/class objects example:this class has `WebDriver driver;` or `UserLogin userlogin = new UserLogin();`
4. I create more classes in `/myproject/src/test/java` by the name of functionality let say "CreateZoo" and extend them with Define class. Later I use methods of these classes in classes inside `/myproject/src/main/java`, for example: A class of Main package would be "DailyTests" and I call methods here from classes inside `/myproject/src/test/java`
5. Apart from this I keep `chromedriverexe`, `properties file`, `data.xls` in main>>resources folder.
6. I also have `CommonFunctions class extends Define` in `/myproject/src/test/java`, here I have written common java functions that I use frequently like :

   ```
   class CommonFunctions extends Define {

   /*
    * 
    * Click linktext, click partial, name,id,xpath,css, classname
    */
   static class clik {

       static void txt(String locator) {
           new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                   ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                           .linkText(locator))).click();
       }
   ```

   and another common fucntions class for myproject like: I have written a long method for user login and I call it where ever I need it.
   So, the way I am doing above is good or should I have classes by the name of each page, for example "LoginPage.java"
   This class would've html elements defined using pagefactory(as of now I am not using page factory.)
   I am a selenium2.0 aspirant , I don't have much experience on it. 
   How to beautify code and create/maintain selenium projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code structure is fairly optimal.

But I do have some suggestions:-

- In my opinion, maintainability of test code can be improved we you define classes based on pages instead of functionality.

Consider a scenario where you have to click on manage account>edit>change address. There can be a similar scenario where you have to click on manage account>edit>change username. In both the scenarios the first 2 steps are same. But they have to be written twice one in ChangeAddress Class and other in ChangeUserNameClass. If property of edit changes, we have to change the code in places. So less maintainability and redundant code.

This can be avoided by defining classes according to functionality. Class1 contains clickManageAccount(), Class2 contains clickEdit() and Class3 contains clickChangeAddress() and changeUserName().
So it is just a matter of assembling the methods above methods in a Junit class based on the functionality.

This will ensure each Test is modular and maintainable. Also page factory can be efficiently used in each class.

- Please consider the following folder structure :-

/myproject/src/test/java/page - Contains all your page classes which extends define class

/myproject/src/test/java/common - Contains all common classes and define class

/myproject/src/test/java/scenarios - Contains JUnit test class with @Before[setUp()], @After[tearDown()] and @Test methods. @Test Methods use methods in page classes to assemble the required methods for a particular scenario.

/myproject/src/main/resources - Contains resources like chromedriverexe, properties file, data.xls

/myproject/src/main/java/ - Contains classes like DailyTests which use classes in /myproject/src/test/java/scenarios

This is just my thoughts. Please do revert back with your ideas on it.

Comment: I am a newbie, I can't say it is the right approach, but it seems nice. *******1. What about defining `html elements` on `page.class` itself using `page factory` instead of defining it in separate class/package naming `objectrepo.class` *******2. What about using `testng groups` to run `testsuite`, is this nice approach??

Comment: 1. Yes, object repository class is a good concept. Code becomes more modular and maintainable. But what we will have to take care while using this approach would be to follow proper naming convention for the html elements because same type elements can be present in different pages. Another approach is creating objrep.class for each page.class

Comment: 2. TestNG framework is a good framework for automation with Selenium. It has several advantages over Junit like parallel execution, proper reporting etc. Refer to the following :-http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/free-selenium-training.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at implementing cucumber (with Selenium): http://cukes.info/

It'll make your code OO, cleaner, and easier to maintain and read.

Comment: Thanks whitney but I am not asking about technology here, I am aware about that. I am asking about structure, or like I said, content and convention or best approach to follow.